# What does "people of good will" mean in Encyclicals?

Tags: catholicism, papacy, encyclicals

Many encyclicals are directed not only to Catholics but to all "people of good will". Just a few examples:

- [Laudato si](http://w2.vatican.va/content/francesco/en/encyclicals/documents/papa-francesco_20150524_enciclica-laudato-si.html):

> 62. Why should this document, addressed to all people of good will, include a chapter dealing with ...

- [Pacem in Terram](http://w2.vatican.va/content/john-xxiii/en/encyclicals/documents/hf_j-xxiii_enc_11041963_pacem.html):

> [...] and to the Clergy and Faithful of the entire Catholic World, and to all Men of Good Will.

- [Populorum Progressio](http://w2.vatican.va/content/paul-vi/en/encyclicals/documents/hf_p-vi_enc_26031967_populorum.html):

> To the Bishops, Priests, Religious, and Faithful of the Whole Catholic World, and to All Men of Good Will.

Is there an **official** understanding by the Catholic church of what people of good will mean?

I searched through the [Cathecism](http://www.vatican.va/archive/ENG0015/_INDEX.HTM), but the [two references](http://www.vatican.va/archive/ENG0015/4/GR.HTM) to good-will that exists are not related to the above. I also searched the [Catholic Encyclopedia](http://www.newadvent.org/cathen/05413a.htm), without success.

Comment: it probably means what it says, men (people) of good will (who want to understand Catholic beliefs and/or who believe in Jesus Christ)....so these documents are meant for everyone who is curious

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This use is generally a reference to the [Greater Doxology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gloria_in_excelsis_Deo) which goes, in its second verse, *"et in terra pax **hominibus bonae voluntatis**"*: "And peace on Earth to the people of good will."

This is a translation of (part of) Lk 2:14, which goes in Greek *"καὶ ἐπὶ γῆς εἰρήνη ἐν ἀνθρώποις εὐδοκίας"*: "And on Earth peace, to men good will", which has a slightly different sense. The Latin translation is traditionally attributed to [St. Hilary of Poitiers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilary_of_Poitiers) in the mid-4th Century. This translation predates the Vulgate, but this part shows up the same in the Vulgate (in the previous verse, Jerome says *in altissimis Deo* where Hilary says *in excelsis Deo*).

Following the sense of the Greater Doxology and of the Scriptural passage, "men of good will" is a reference to those men who are well disposed to hear the Word of God and take it to heart, and who are referred to by the angels in the Gospel.